# How to postMessage through port when websocket receives the word.?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, websocket

I am trying to use the websocket's onMessage function so that when it receives the word "go", it will postMessage through the port for the current tab. The current tab id is valid, but I keep getting the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'postMessage' of undefined.

```
ws.onmessage = function (evt) {  
if(evt.data == "connect"){
  rpwd = "helloworld";
    ports[curTabID].postMessage({text: rpwd});
}
};
```

Comment: How is `ports` built, maintained, and where do you get `curTabID`? -1 for now for insufficient information; read [this help article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and edit your post accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my mistaking ports and tab.id to be the same thing. The postMessage must be called on a port. I had to add in an onConnect listener to get the port for whatever tab was opened.

```
var ports = {};
function onConnect(port) {
ports[port.sender.tab.id] = port;
}
chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener(onConnect);
```

After that, I needed to know what my current tab id was so that I can look it up in the ports array, which is populated by the onConnect.

```
var curTabID = 0;

chrome.tabs.onSelectionChanged.addListener(function(tabId) {
    curTabID = tabId;
});
```

From that, I was able to get the port info necessary to send the postMessage.

```
ws.onmessage = function (evt) {  
    if(evt.data == "connect"){
        rpwd = "helloworld";
        ports[curTabID].postMessage({text: rpwd});
}
};
```

I struggled pretty hard with this code, so I hope I can save somebody time.

Comment: You don't have to keep track of the active tab like this. `chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, ...);` will find the current tab on demand.